# Why are new node instances not available after Increasing GKE Cluster's Node Pool size?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm relatively new to K8's, and I've setup a private cluster with a single node pool on GKE. The node pool was configured to have nodes on 3 zones in a single GCP region (Autoscaling enabled with minimum of 2 nodes and maximum of 20 total nodes).

I ran into the following error upon trying to deploy new resources: `Cannot schedule pods: Insufficient memory.` I decided to disable Autoscaling on cluster's node pool, and then manually increase the number of nodes. I applied the change, each Instance Group now has 3 instances (a total of 9). However, the instances listed under the 'Nodes' section of the GKE Console does not reflect that. It show only 5 (which is actually a decrease from the original 6).

[image]

GCP DOCS:
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/resizing-a-cluster

What am I missing here? Thanks

Comment: What do the logs show after resizing?

Comment: I had similar problem in past. It was caused by version mismatch, where nodepool GKE version was lower than cluster GKE version.

Comment: Looks like you have a misconfigured resource Requests/Limits. 4 out of 5 of your workers are almost at `65%`+ CPU requested, and, 1 worker is in `unknown` state. I would suggest removing any  resource limits/requests from your any resources you are trying to deploy.

Comment: @Hitobat You were right, it was a mismatch issue between the version of the cluster & node pool.

Comment: @hdhruna Could you elaborate on your comment regarding the resource requests / limits? What impact does that have on this issue?

Comment: @bahmsto we faced a similar issue on our GKE cluster and it had to do with Resource Limits/Requests, surprisingly similar use case as yours. However, the only difference was the GKE Control Plane was one version higher than the node-pools.

Comment: Based on [this article](https://www.papertrail.com/solution/tips/kubernetes-logging-tips-to-avoid-memory-and-resource-issues/): "Without requests and limits set, pods will simply be managed on a first-come, first-served basis. Kubernetes will try to distribute RAM between all running pods equally, but if one pod tries to allocate more and more memory, Kubernetes may kick out other pods from the node to meet the demand. There’s nothing stopping pods from consuming all the free memory on the node."

Comment: Hello, any updates here?

Comment: Do you need any further help with this case? Is it clear for you?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here was caused by mismatch between versions of the cluster and node pool.

> By default, [automatic upgrades](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-upgrades#upgrading_automatically) are enabled for Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) clusters and node pools.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/upgrading-a-cluster#upgrading-nodes) is documentation that helps to upgrade cluster or node pool manually.

---

Upgrading to the default cluster version can be done by running the following command:

```
gcloud container clusters upgrade CLUSTER_NAME --master
```

---

All nodes can be updated to the same version as the control plane by running this command:

```
gcloud container clusters upgrade
```

Following command should be used in case rolling back an upgrade:

```
gcloud container node-pools rollback NODE_POOL_NAME \  --cluster CLUSTER_NAME
```

---

See also [this reference](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/upgrade) and [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-upgrades#how_cluster_and_node_pool_upgrades_work).